# Mapping contracts to ganache addresses

Tags: truffle, ganache

I am deploying a factory contract to ganache using `truffle migrate`.

In response to user events my factory deploys other contracts. All the contracts are in the `truffle-config.js` I associate with ganache and are visible in the workspace

However, I only actually deploy the factory using `truffle migrate`, I never use that to deploy the other contracts. As a result ganache doesn't seem to know about any of the other contracts or events in my project.

The newly deployed contracts are visible in ganache as addresses, but are not recognized as being of the types in my project.

Is there a way to map contracts that are deployed by my factory to addresses that ganache knows about? Also events?

Do I have to deploy all the contracts in my project to ganache once?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your Factory contract doesn't deploy other contracts just using them to create an instance (like creating instance in OOP). When you deploy the Factory contract it also deploys other contracts' code cause you imported them top of the Factory contract.

In addition, you can see the contracts in Ganache on Contract tab if you link your truffle project by specifying truffle-config.js file.

**Updated Answer:**

These answers explain how factory pattern works:

- https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/45918/77376
- https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/14012/77376

Comment: I can see the contracts in the tab in Ganache, but none of them are linked to the contract instances that the factory creates. What I need is a way to tell Ganache that the instance address relates to the contract in question.

Comment: Actually your answer is a bit misleading. The solidity `new` operator that I use in the factory deploys the contract code and returns the address - that's what an `instance` is. The contract list in Ganache is just the list referred to by `truffle-config.js`. I'm no closer to figuring out how I associate a contract listed in the Ganache contracts tab to an address of an instance that has been created by the factory.

Comment: Sorry for my misleading answer. You can check this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/14012/77376). To sum: the transaction initiating the contract creation is not sent to 0x0, but to the factory, so for the EVM it looks like an ordinary function, so the contractAddress field is not set. I guess it means the contract created by another contract doesn't seems as a contract in explorers. The last sentence was like a rhyme xD

Comment: Thanks, yes, that answer lines up with my understanding too. What is missing in Ganache is a way of doing what I would do in either the factory or a user interface via web3, namely associating the resulting address of the newly created/deployed contract to a known construct. I don't think there is a way of doing what I want to do...

Comment: I am not sure but you can use [interfaces](https://cryptozombies.io/en/lesson/2/chapter/11) to associate the resulting address of the newly created/deployed contract to a known construct.